Angular Code Input Component throwing "ERROR ReferenceError: document is not defined
I am using the following library angular-code-input
. However, I encountered an error when a component loaded, which is using the Angular Code Input Component. The error message received is:"
- Changes detected. Rebuilding...
ERROR ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at _CodeInputComponent.focusOnInputAfterAppearing (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/angular-code-input/fesm2022/angular-code-input.mjs:300:52)
    at _CodeInputComponent.ngAfterViewChecked (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/angular-code-input/fesm2022/angular-code-input.mjs:103:10)
    at callHookInternal (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6117:14)
    at callHook (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6148:9)
    at callHooks (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6099:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6049:9)
    at refreshView (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12171:21)
    at detectChangesInView (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12324:9)
    at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12287:5)
    at detectChangesInEmbeddedViews (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12244:13)
ERROR ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at _CodeInputComponent.focusOnInputAfterAppearing (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/angular-code-input/fesm2022/angular-code-input.mjs:300:52)
    at _CodeInputComponent.ngAfterViewChecked (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/angular-code-input/fesm2022/angular-code-input.mjs:103:10)
    at callHookInternal (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web2/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6117:14)
    at callHook (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6148:9)
    at callHooks (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6099:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:6049:9)
    at refreshView (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12171:21)
    at detectChangesInView (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12324:9)
    at detectChangesInViewIfAttached (c:/Users/X/Documents/sourcecode/web/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:12287:5)


Details:
The error originates from the Angular Code Input Component and seems to be related to the usage of document which is not available when navigating to the route that has component that is using the Angular Code Input Component.
Steps to Reproduce:

Start the Angular project.
Navigate to the route containing the component that utilizes the Angular Code Input Component. The component loads, but the terminal shows error logs.

Expected Behavior:
The component loads successfully after navigation without any errors.
Environment:

Angular version: 17.1.0
Operating System: Windows
Node.js version: v18.19.1
npm: 10.2.4


Do you have ssr enabled ?

Hi @MatthieuRiegler, yes application is ssr enabled

This is because angular-code-input library internally might be using document object of window which is not available on server side.
You need to add check for browser.
Something like this,
export class AppService {

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
    this.isServer = isPlatformServer(platformId);
  }
}
<div class="customNavTabs">
   @if (appService.isBrowser) {
     <code-input [isCodeHidden]="true"
              [codeLength]="5"
              (codeChanged)="onCodeChanged($event)"
              (codeCompleted)="onCodeCompleted($event)">
     </code-input>
   }
</div> 


you are indeed correct, I found out that the library doesn't support ssr enabled applications. https://github.com/AlexMiniApps/angular-code-input/issues/115

Yes, you can either find an alternative lib or add a check for the browser.
